# How do I execute multiple querys inside an If inside a procedure?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute two querys that "transfer" money from one bank to the other (one bank is one table), but only if the new balance is above 0. sc_bank and sub_bank are the two tables, amountOfMoney,  customerIDsc and customerIDsub are parameters in the procedure. What am I doing wrong that phpmyadmin gives me multiple SQL sintax errors?

```
BEGIN
    SELECT @A:=sub_bank.value FROM sub_bank WHERE customer_id = customerIDsub;
    IF @A - amountOfMoney > 0 THEN 
        UPDATE sc_bank SET sc_bank.value = sc_bank.value + amountOfMoney WHERE sc_bank.customer_id = customerIDsc;
        UPDATE sub_bank SET sub_bank.value = sub_bank.value - amountOfMoney WHERE sub_bank.customer_id = customerIDsub;
    END IF

END;
```

Edit:
This is the function that phpmyadmin tries to execute to create the procedure, it seems like it puts the IF in the WHERE statement of the first update

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proceduro`(
    IN `amountOfMoney` DECIMAL(6, 2),
    IN `customerIDsc` INT(10),
    IN `customerIDsub` INT(10)
) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @A := sub_bank.value
    FROM
        sub_bank
    WHERE
        customer_id = customerIDsub; IF @A - amountOfMoney > 0 THEN
    UPDATE
        sc_bank
    SET
        sc_bank.value = sc_bank.value + amountOfMoney
    WHERE
        sc_bank.customer_id = customerIDsc;
    UPDATE
        sub_bank
    SET
        sub_bank.value = sub_bank.value - amountOfMoney
    WHERE
        sub_bank.customer_id = customerIDsub;
END IF
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task does not need in "new balance is above 0" checking - it can be easily performed by according column CHECK constraint. Then simply update both tables in a transaction - if the balance should fall below zero then constraint violation occures, transaction fails and rolled back.

See [DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9817023c7db622a7edcd91cb98ae9d0)

Pay attention - the query which may fail due to constraint violation is the most upper. If you swap UPDATE queries then the balance for acceptor will be altered errorneously. In such case you must declare according handler and rollback the transaction if it fires.

See [DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc1f4d50b04ef5d22a4b12187a4e73a6)